# Scaling HTML from transcribed PDF files

Tags: php, html, css, media-queries, html-to-pdf

I have a few PDF files that were converted to HTML. I fully understand that this isn't ideal, but that's not something I can change.

The issue is that it places content at very specific points which breaks mobile responsiveness.

A typical HTML will looks like this:

```
<div class="pc pc1 w0 h0">

<div class="t m0 x0 h2 y1 ff1 fs0 fc0 sc0 ls0 ws0">Text</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS file like this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
.sc_{-webkit-text-stroke:0px transparent;}
.sc0{-webkit-text-stroke:0.015em transparent;text-shadow:none;}
}
.ws0{word-spacing:0.000000px;}
.fc0{color:rgb(35,31,32);}
.fs0{font-size:168.000000px;}
.y0{bottom:781.000000px;}
.h0{height:841.889770px;}
.w0{width:595.275630px;}
.x0{left:34.000000px;}
}
```

Is it possible to somehow make it scale? I'd even be happy(-ier) if I could just apply a media query to reduce everything in size by 20%.

Comment: Simply by setting `transform: scale(0.8)` on the outer most div will scale it by 20%.

Comment: Thanks! Scaling it like that was my thought as well...I guess there really isn't a more elegant solution, correct?

Comment: As it appears from the posted CSS, `position: absolute` is used, so I can't see any other, if not to rewrite the html

Comment: That's what I thought as well.

Comment: Actually I have one more question. If I change the print media query to one for responsive using width parameters, is there a way to do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears from the posted CSS, `position: absolute` is used, so I can't see any other solution (yet) than using `transform: scale()` (if not to rewrite the html of course)

By using media query it could look like this

```css
.outer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .outer {
     transform: scale(0.9);
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
   .outer {
     transform: scale(0.8);
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   .outer {
     transform: scale(0.7);
   }
}
height: 400px;
width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked better than expected.

Comment: @Procyon82 You're welcome, and if you often deal with PDF's, this library is interesting: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js